# Where are Setters in DataTemplate.Triggers applied when no TargetName is given?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datatemplate, datatrigger

In my scenario, I have an `ItemsControl` where the `DataTemplate` needs to change in a few ways depending on the properties of the item. One of the things that needs to change is the context menu for the item.

I've put together this example to show my situation. Take the following classes:

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Property Things As New List(Of Thing) From {New Thing With {.Name = "Thing 1", .Type = ThingType.A},
                                                       New Thing With {.Name = "Thing 2", .Type = ThingType.B},
                                                       New Thing With {.Name = "Thing 3", .Type = ThingType.C}}
End Class

Public Class Thing
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As ThingType
End Class

Public Enum ThingType
    A
    B
    C
End Enum
```

`Thing` has some data to display (`Name`), and something that should influence the template (`Type`).

Now take the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VBTest"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="DefaultMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="A or C"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="BMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="B Only"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:Thing">
                <TextBlock Name="Title" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="B">
                        <Setter TargetName="Title" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource BMenu}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>    
</Window>
```

In `DataTemplate.Triggers`, I define a trigger for items of type `B`. For these items, I want to change some aspects of the template, so I use `TargetName` on the `Setter` to change the `FontWeight` of a `TextBlock` (in the real code I change a number of properties for a number of elements). But I also want to change the `ContextMenu` for the entire item. To do this, I use a `Setter` *without* `TargetName` and the property `ContextMenu`.

The above *works* somehow. If you run this and right-click "Thing 2" you see `BMenu`. But *how* does this work? What object is the `Setter` being applied to? `DataTemplate` has no `ContextMenu` property.

And I ask this for more than just curiosity. I want all other types of items (`A` and `C`) to use `DefaultMenu`. That should be the default, with the `DataTrigger` overriding it for `B` items. But I don't even know what object I'm `Setter`-ing at this point, so I don't know where or how to set this default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What object is the Setter being applied to?

It's applied to the `ContentPresenter` item container that wraps each element in the `Things` source collection.

You can set the default `ContextMenu` using an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DefaultMenu}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. For the method of setting the default: What if I were using the same `DataTemplate` in a number of different types of `ItemsControl`. Would there be any way around having to set the `ItemContainerStyle` for each one?

Comment: @KeithStein: Not apart from applying the `ContextMenu` to an element in the `DataTemplate` itself I guess.

Comment: I managed to get around having to use an `ItemContainerStyle` for the default value. Instead I created an "always true" `DataTrigger` where both the binding source and the value were `x:Null`. As long as I define my real triggers after that one, they take precedence. It's a little ugly, but at least it lets me keep everything inside the one `DataTemplate`.